# cache list in CMake

Tags: caching, cmake

Is is possible to use list instead of variables in case of cache variables?

Here how I use cache variables

```
set(VAR "Value" CACHE INTERNAL "My Var")
set(VAR "${VAR} Value2" CACHE INTERNAL "My Var")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CMake lists are semi-colon separated, so you can `set` the list directly like this:

```
set(VAR Value;Value2 CACHE INTERNAL "My Var")
```

Having said that, even though lists are held as semi-colon separated items, they can be constructed using `set` with spaces between each item; e.g.

```
set(MyList Value Value2)  # list is  Value;Value2
```

So, if your values contain spaces, you need to wrap the list in quotation marks `"`:

```
set(VAR "Value 1;Value 2" CACHE INTERNAL "My Var")  # list is  Value 1;Value 2
```

The final point is that if you already have your list constructed, you don't need to wrap the list variable in quotation marks when caching it:

```
set(MyList "Value 1;Value 2")  # list is  Value 1;Value 2
set(VAR ${MyList} CACHE INTERNAL "My Var")  # no quotes required
```

#### Edit:

As I now understand it, you're asking if the `list(APPEND...)` command can be used to cache values directly.

The answer is no, but you were almost correct in your attempt.  To get the desired effect, you'd need to use a semi-colon rather than space when caching the list:

```
set(VAR "${VAR};Value2" CACHE INTERNAL "My Var")
```

Comment: What if I don't want to append values in several times. Can I use list(APPEND...)?

Comment: You can't use `list(APPEND...)` to get the values into the cache.  You'd need to wait until the list is complete, then cache it using `set(... CACHE ...)`.  You can use the same name for the list variable as the cache variable.

Comment: Oh - I see!  Your original question is if you can use the CMake command `list` to get variables into cache?